# Why is unit testing not working in this D program?

Tags: unit-testing, d, visual-d

Why does unit testing work for program 1, but not for program 2 below?

**Program 1**

```
import std.stdio;

unittest
{
    assert(false);
}

void main()
{
    writeln("Hello D-World!");
}
```

**Program 2**

```
module winmain;

import core.sys.windows.windows;

unittest {
    assert(false);
}

extern (Windows)
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR
lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Both programs were compiled with the `-unittest` option (by running `dmd -unittest <program.d>`). When run, program 1 displays the unit test failure, but program 2 does not. What am I missing?

**Update**: reformulated question & added working example.

**Update 2**: also compiled with `dmd -debug -unittest <program.d>`, with similar results.

Comment: did you also compile in debug mode?

Comment: yes, and I also compiled outside Visual Studio with `dmd` directly (`dmd -unittest winmain.d`)

Comment: try with `dmd -debug -unittest winmain.d`

Comment: I tried `-debug` as you suggested from the command line as well. No joy :(

Comment: who voted this down? it is a legitimate question to me...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is kinda simple: in program one, the unittests are actually run, by the runtime in program two, they aren't because the unit test function is never called, since declaring your own WinMain (or even extern(C) main) bypasses the runtime initialization and setup that is usually done automatically before it calls your D main - code done in a C main.

Open up your dmd zip and get to the file dmd2/src/druntime/src/rt/dmain2.d. Find the function _d_run_main().

When a D program with a regular D main is started up, the compiler inserts a C main which calls _d_run_main(). This function, as you can see looking through the source, does a bunch of things:

- it initializes the floating point hardware to the mode D expects
- it formats the command line arguments into D strings
- it initializes the runtime
- it runs the unit tests <<--- super important to you!
- it runs the D main, wrapped in a try/catch block for default exception handling
- it terminates the runtime
- it flushes output and returns

Yes, on line 399 (of the version I have, might be a bit different in your version of druntime's source), you'll see these lines:

```
    if (rt_init() && runModuleUnitTests()) 
        tryExec({ result = mainFunc(args); });
```

Yup, unit tests are run separately from rt_init (also known as Runtime.initialize). The way the compiler -unittest switch works is it just doesn't compile the unittest functions, so runModuleUnitTests sees a bunch of null tests, which it skips. Thus you can call the function in your custom main without worrying about the compiler switch.

Since you have a custom main and didn't call `runModuleUnitTests` (defined in `core.runtime` btw), the unit tests never happen. They are called before *D* main, but still inside *c* main or *Win*main.

My recommendation is to avoid the use of `WinMain` in D, instead preferring to write regular D mains. You can get the arguments passed to `WinMain` with API functions like `GetCommandLineW`, and `GetModuleHandle`. (`nCmdShow` is rarely used anyway and I think `hPrevInstance` is legacy leftover from the 16 bit days, so I doubt you'd care about them anyway!)

The presence of `WinMain` also signals the linker that you're writing a GUI program and thus should use the Windows subsystem - you don't get a console. You can do this explicitly too by passing `-L/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS:5.0` to dmd when compiling on Windows 32 bit. (The /SUBSYSTEM argument is one of optlink's switches.) On Windows 64, I'm not sure, but it is probably similar if not identical - check the Microsoft linker's docs for choosing subsystem, I'm sure it is there.

Between that linker switch and the two API calls to fetch the arguments, you don't need WinMain anymore so it saves you the trouble of reimplementing what the runtime's `_d_run_main` function does yourself.

If you do want to use it anyway, there's two options: just call `_d_run_main` - look at the source code for the signature it expects. It takes a pointer to the main function so you could reuse all that. Or, you can `import core.runtime;` and call the `Runtime.initialize(); runModuleUnitTests(); your main here... Runtime.terminate();` yourself. Don't forget to check return values and handle exceptions too! You need to do it in the right order and handle errors correctly or you'll see crashes.

All this same applies if you are writing your own `extern(C) main` as well as your own `WinMain`.

Again though, you're probably better off avoiding it and just writing a regular D main function, with the linker switch to turn off the console on your gui app.